# Where can I get the uploaded file in Meteor Files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am using Meteor and React JS. I also added Meteor Files.

https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files

By using this code,

```
this.Images = new FilesCollection({collectionName: 'Images'});
export default class Logo extends TrackerReact(React.Component){
    constructor(){
    ...
    Meteor.subscribe('files.images.all');
    }
uploadLogo(e){
    if (e.currentTarget.files && e.currentTarget.files[0]) {
      // We upload only one file, in case 
      // there was multiple files selected
      var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
      if (file) {
        var uploadInstance = Images.insert({
          file: file,
          streams: 'dynamic',
          chunkSize: 'dynamic',
          transport: 'http'
        }, false);

        uploadInstance.on('start', function() {
          //template.currentUpload.set(this);
        });

        uploadInstance.on('end', function(error, fileObj) {
          if (error) {
            alert('Error during upload: ' + error.reason);
          } else {
              console.log("done");
            alert('File "' + fileObj.name + '" successfully uploaded');
          }
        });
        uploadInstance.start();
      }

    }else{
        console.log("error");
    }
}
render(){
...
<input type="file" id="fileinput" onChange={this.uploadLogo.bind(this)} />
}
```

I am able to upload the file but I don't see any files in my directory.
Here is my publish.js,

```
this.Images = new Meteor.Files({
  debug: true,
  collectionName: 'Images',
  allowClientCode: false, // Disallow remove files from Client
  onBeforeUpload: function (file) {
    // Allow upload files under 10MB, and only in png/jpg/jpeg formats
    if (file.size <= 1024*1024*10 && /png|jpg|jpeg/i.test(file.extension)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return 'Please upload image, with size equal or less than 10MB';
    }
  }
});
Meteor.publish('files.images.all', function () {
    return Images.find().cursor;
  });
```

How can I display the image? How can I limit the user to upload files that are only images?

For me, their API Docs is not rich. I can't understand what the things they are talking in their docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default uploaded files are stored in the file system. Read the FAQ:

> **Where are files stored by default?**: by default if config.storagePath
> isn't passed into Constructor it's equals to assets/app/uploads and
> relative to running script:
>
> - On development stage:
>   yourDevAppDir/.meteor/local/build/programs/server
>
> Note: All files
> will be removed as soon as your application rebuilds or you run meteor
> reset. To keep your storage persistent during development use an
> absolute path outside of your project folder, e.g. /data directory.
>
> - On production: yourProdAppDir/programs/server

So you need to set a location with *config.storagePath*